# Using disposed observer does not re-subscribe to the source

Tags: java, android, rx-android, rx-java2

I'm trying to reuse an `Observer` for a `Single` and `Observable` stream by creating only a single instance of `DisposableSingleObserver/DisposableObserver` and passing them through it through the `subscribeWith()` method on the stream like below:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private DisposableSingleObserver<Object> observer;

    public SomeClass() {
        observer = new DisposableSingleObserver<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Object object) {
                ...
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                ...
            }
        };
    }

    public void doSomeStuff() {
        singleStream.subscribeOn(...)
            .observeOn(...)
            .subscribeWith(observer);
    }
}
```

The above code resulted in `ProtocolViolationException` when I tried to subscribe with the single observer instance multiple times with message:

> io.reactivex.exceptions.ProtocolViolationException: It is not allowed to subscribe with a(n) com.package.name.SomeClass$1 multiple times. Please create a fresh instance of com.package.name.SomeClass$1 and subscribe that to the target source instead.

So I modified the code a bit like below:

```
public class SomeClass {
    ...

    public void doSomeStuff() {
        if (observer != null) {
            observer.dispose();
        }

        singleStream.subscribeOn(...)
            .observerOn(...)
            .subscribeWith(observer);
    }
}
```

When I executed the above code, the `ProtocolViolationException` was no longer thrown and I was able to get event from the single stream successfully. But when I tried to call `doSomeStuff()` method couple of time, it completed successfully on first call but did not emit any event on second call. I was able to confirm that the subscription happened through `doOnSubscribe()` both times but the code emitting event for single stream was never executed on second call. So I have three questions:

1. Why was the `ProtocolViolationException` thrown in the first place?
2. Why was I able to get the event on first subscription but not on the second subscription even though we subscribed to the source in both cases?
3. How can I reuse observer by using only a single instance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) You are not allowed to reuse the `DisposableSingleObserver` and its cousins as they are stateful and one time use only. This is due to the protocol mandated by `Single`: exactly one `onSubscribe` followed by at most one `onSuccess` or `onError`. A second subscription violates this protocol.

2) Disposing the `DisposableSingleObserver` puts it in a disposed state and any subsequent subscription attempt will be considered as immediately disposed.

3) You shouldn't. Why do you want to subscribe multiple times and why can't you use a new `DisposableSingleObserver` each time. You should rethink your dataflow.

Comment: Is 1&2 also true for `DisposableObserver`? About 3, I am trying to limit the number of instances for the Observers.

Comment: I referred to those as "its cousins" yes.

Comment: Cool answer. I guess I am getting the same exception when re-subscribing to the same instance of my implementation of `DisposableObserver`.

Comment: I also found that this "subscribe once" is clearly described in the javadoc of `DisposableObserver`, see http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/observers/DisposableObserver.html:

(Like all other consumers, `DisposableObserver` can be subscribed only once. Any subsequent attempt to subscribe it to a new source will yield an `IllegalStateException with message "It is not allowed to subscribe with a(n) <class name> multiple times.".`) .